# Unable to find the socket transport "SSL" but SSL seems to be installed

Tags: php, sockets, email, ssl, laravel

On Laravel Forge (Nginx 1.6, PHP 5.5, has OpenSSL installed out of the box) I get the following exception when trying to send an e-mail:

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Unable to find the socket transport "SSL" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? #32638]

However, OpenSSL seems to be installed and enabled, because the command `openssl version -a` gives a recent version. Phpinfo mentions ssl and sslv3 as registered socket transports, and lists OpenSSL as enabled.

If I do:

```
php -i | grep -i openss
```

It returns some results:

```
SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.0.1f
openssl
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
OpenSSL support => enabled
```

So why am I still getting this error? Is it not properly installed, or might it have to do with my mail settings?

```
EMAIL_HOST  smtp.gmail.com
EMAIL_PORT  587
EMAIL_ENCRYPTION    TLS
(email ...@gmail.com and pw private ofc)
```

(I've tried the SSL email encryption as well with the port 465.)

I'm at a loss as to how to fix this, so help would be appreciated!

Comment: commnad-line php and web-based php usually haev different config files. seeing ssl installed in the cli version means nothing if you're doing the ssl stuff in web-based code. you'll have to check `phpinfo()` inside your mail-sending script and see what comes up there. phpinfo() will also tell you WHICH .ini files were loaded/processed.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for your response! my phpinfo file also says OpenSSL is enabled, as is the transport :). As I said, the Forge provisioner configures the domain with OpenSSL in PHP by default.

Comment: I stumbled on the same error. Did you ever found the fix ?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? I'm experiencing the same on my Laravel app.